# NgZone tries to mutate a Promise in ngrx store

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am using an implementation of Redux from ngrx and create modal dialog windows in my application using NgbModal from ng-bootstrap. I need to store the [reference to the modal window](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal#NgbModalRef), which is an object with one of the properties being a promise, and the application store is the right place for that. However, when I do the following:

```
const modalRef: NgbModalRef = this.modal.open(PINModalComponent);
this.store.dispatch({type: TwoFAActions.STORE_PIN_MODAL_REF, payload: modalRef});
```

I get this:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_nesting' of object '#<NgZone>'
    at NgZone.onLeave (core.es5.js:4165)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4119)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.988.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:366)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.988.Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
    at HTMLButtonElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:420)
```

It looks like NgZone tries to mutate the promise which is a part of the action payload, but cannot do that because ngrx makes the objects in its store immutable. Any ideas how to elegantly circumvent this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the payload with a getter function and that did it:

```
const modalRef: NgbModalRef = this.modal.open(PINModalComponent);
this.store.dispatch({type: TwoFAActions.STORE_PIN_MODAL_REF, payload: () => modalRef});
```